# Robokassa. Как вывести кнопку на странице?

Tags: perl, robokassa

Всем привет. туплю уже, Robokassa дает код:

```
print "<html><script language=JavaScript ".
      "src='https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/PaymentForm/FormL.js?".
      "MrchLogin=$mrh_login&OutSum=$out_summ&InvId=$inv_id&IncCurrLabel=$in_curr".
      "&Desc=$inv_desc&SignatureValue=$crc&Shp_item=$shp_item".
      "&Culture=$culture&Encoding=$encoding'></script></html>"
```

Замечательно. Но мне то нужно на своей странице кнопку вывести!
Пишу:

```
$online_pay = qq~
      <script language=JavaScript ".
      "src='https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/PaymentForm/FormL.js?".
      "MrchLogin=$mrh_login&OutSum=$out_summ&InvId=$inv_id&IncCurrLabel=$in_curr".
      "&Desc=$inv_desc&SignatureValue=$crc&Shp_item=$shp_item".
      "&Culture=$culture&Encoding=$encoding'></script>
~;
```

Затем через

```
    HTML::Template->
online_pay => $online_pay
    <TMPL_VAR NAME="online_pay">
```

Не работает! В исходном коде странице этот код весь красный и браузером не интерпретируется никак. Я с JavaScript не очень, помогите пожалуйста. Почему он не выполняется.

Comment: Вот эти все `".` в конце строк и `"` в начале строк для того что бы собрать строку, в браузер должно уйти только их содержимое. А вы открываете собственную одну "кавычку" `~` и в итоге отправляете в браузер текст вместе со всеми кавычками, которые должны были интерпретироваться на стороне сервера. в браузер должно придти `<script src='....'></script>`

Comment: Точно! Всё получилось. Спасибо!!!